# Changing ArcGIS Online Map Interface?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-portal

How do i change the map interface in arcgis online and portal? I have been trying to find a clear answer online for about a week and I have yet to find anything helpful from ESRI or any forum.

Basically I wanna go from this kind of interfance[image]

To this
[image]

I dont have a lot of experience with arcgis Portal so please bear with me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for AGO web templates.

http://www.arcgis.com/home/gallery.html#c=esri&t=apps&o=modified&f=configurable

https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/create-app-templates.htm

You download the template, and configure it how you want, including your styles, basemaps, etc.  Then create the app.